# Flutter update keep rejected due to REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES

Tags: android, flutter

I've googled many solutions on this website. Even after I've removed open_file packages, execute flutter clean and build again, but still get rejected from play store with the same reason. I've tried the following but with no luck:

1. Added this  into my Manifest.xml`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>`
2. Removed open_file package, run flutter clean and rebuild.
3. Open android studio, analyze the APK and couldn't find any REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES.
4. Open app bundle explorer, no found any REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES.
5. Checked \build\app\outputs\logs\manifest-merger-release-report.txt, same result no REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES.

However, each time I upload I still get rejected for the same reason.

Comment: Did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  did you import this package for delete permission?.
if you ddint import package for delete permission permission dont work try add  as

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="packageName">

Comment: Yes, i've added the command, without it i won't able to compile and show error.

Comment: can you send your android manifest file text here?

Comment: can you send your android manifest file text here? –

Answer (score 0):

Still having issue, here is my manifest file :

"xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove" />
```

Answer (score -2):

I added the following command but google still reject my app bundle..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: This isn't an answer if you still have issues. This would be better suited as a comment instead.

Comment: It is not an answer. It is enough to vote up the question.